# Android Camera - the moving cube

Tags: android

I am new with android,and I hope that you will help me.
I use opencv-android library ,i have tried to run the camera preview sample,but unfortunately i get a cube moving on the screen, i have tried to write my own code but i faced the same problem also changing the API didn`t fix the problem.

(see the attached link which shows a Image that explain what i mean).
thank you in advance)
Image:
http://imageshack.us/photo/my-images/811/cubee.png/

Answer (score 2):

This is normal when you use the emulator.

It has no hardware camera/webcam support, so you get this grid with the moving block as a replacement for the actual camera preview *(if you open the default camera app, you will get the same thing)*.

When you run the same code on an actual device, it will show a correct, normal preview with real pictures from the hardware.